# Does using two indices to edit an array using a loop decrease time complexity from O(n) to O(log n)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

Say I have a string of characters, and I wish to camel case it. That is `"hello this is john"` should be `"Hello This Is John"`. A linear way to provide a solution to string `s` would be to go through each character and update the string using a temporary variable such as:

```
finished+=s.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
     for(var i=1; i < s.length; i++)
     {
        if(s.charAt(i) != " ")
        {
            finished+=s.charAt(i);

        }
    else
    {
        finished+=" ";
        finished+=s.charAt(i+1).toUpperCase();
        i++;

    }
alert(finished);
```

My question is would it be more efficient if given a string s of n length, we start the solution on indices on both the beginning( working forward) and ending(working backwards) on the string? Such as:

```
var s="hello this is Nithin";
var begin="";
var back="";
begin+=s.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
i=1;
j=s.length-1;
 while(i < j)
 {
    if(s.charAt(i) != " ")
    {
        begin+=s.charAt(i);

    }
    else
    {
        begin+=" ";
        begin+=s.charAt(i+1).toUpperCase();
        i++;

    }
  if(s.charAt(j-1) === " ")
    {
        var temp = " " + s.charAt(j).toUpperCase();
        back= temp + back;
        j--;
    }
  else
    {
        back= s.charAt(j) + back;
    }
    i++;
    j--;
}
alert(begin+back);
```

Mainly, would this go from being O(n) complexity to O(log n) complexity?

Comment: No. You still perform `n` operations.

Comment: Is there any benefit from doing the double index approach?

Comment: None that I can think of, apart from creativity.

Comment: Okay, thanks @AJFarmar

Comment: RegExp should be a bit faster, because of the multiple `+=` string concatenations seem kind of inefficient http://jsben.ch/vo3W1

Comment: Where in this algorithm is there a logarithmic number of steps?

Comment: I assumed it could be logarithmic because of the two indices working backwards. The loop would run much faster was the idea.